# swapping address values of pointers

Tags: pointers

Below is code and I want to ask, why I am not getting swapped number as a result, because instead of swapping numbers I tried to swap their addresses.

```
    int *swap(int *ptr1,int *ptr2){
    int *temp;
    temp = ptr1;
    ptr1= ptr2;
    ptr2=temp;
    return ptr1,ptr2;
}
int main(){
    int num1=2,num2=4,*ptr1=&num1,*ptr2=&num2;
    swap(ptr1,ptr2);
    printf("\nafter swaping the first number is : %d\t and the second number is : %d\n",*ptr1,*ptr2);
}
```

Comment: You use pointers to change the values that the pointers contain as a means of passing by reference.  Though if the value *is* the pointer, you need to pass a double pointer to swap pointer values.  You did the equivalent of `void swap(int val1, int val2) { int temp;  temp=val1; val1=val2; val2=temp; }` but for pointers.

Comment: That said, you’re swapping *the parameters of your function*, which are temporary copies, not the values they point to.  Also, your return statement only appears to work because C has a comma operator.  What you want to do is pass the arguments by reference, then dereference them, without returning anything.  Do you really want to swap `ptr1` and `ptr2` in `main`, the different variables in `swap` that happen to have the same names, or `num1` and `num2`?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems in your code.

First, within the `swap` function, `ptr1` and `ptr2` are local copies of the pointers in `main` with the same name.  Changing them in `swap` only changes those copies, not the originals.

Second, the `return` statement doesn't do anything useful.  The function `swap` is declared as returning a single `int *`.  The return statement actually only returns `ptr2` - for why that is, look up the "comma operator" in C.  But you ignore the return value in `main` anyway, so it makes no odds.

Comment: If he answered your question satisfactorily, please award the answer, so that others will know in future.